# why the validation did not work & jump to another page?

Tags: php, validation

I wrote a customer_display.php to validate data (only First Name so far), but no matter First Name field is empty or not, the webpage will jump to customer_search.php & did not change information in database. why?

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 // Initialize variables and set to empty strings
$firstName=$lastName="";
$firstNameErr=$lastNameErr="";

// Control variables
$app_state = "empty";  //empty, processed, logged in
$valid = 0;

// Validate input and sanitize
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
if(isset($_POST["first_name"]))
{
   if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
  $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
}
else {
  $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
  if(strlen($firstName)>5){
      $firstNameErr = "First name is too long";
  }
  else{
  $valid++;
}
}

  }
if (empty($_POST["lastName"])) {
  $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
}
else {
  $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
  $valid++;
}

if ($valid >= 2) {
  $app_state = "processed";
}
}

// Sanitize data
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

if ($app_state == "empty") {
?>
<!-- display a table of customer information -->
<h2>View/Update Customer</h2>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="POST" id="aligned">
    <input type="hidden" value="update_customer">
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['customerID']); ?>">

    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['firstName']); ?>">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $firstNameErr;?></span><br>



    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['lastName']); ?>"><br>

    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['address']); ?>" 
           size="50"><br>

    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['city']); ?>"><br>

    <label>State:</label>
    <input type="text" name="state" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['state']); ?>"><br>

    <label>Postal Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="postal_code" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['postalCode']); ?>"><br>

    <label>Country:</label>
    <select name="selected">
     <?php  

        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass ='';
        $db = 'tech_support';

        $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
        if($conn->connect_error)
            die('Could not connect: '. $conn->connect_error);


        $selected= $conn->query("select * from countries where countryCode = '" .$customer['countryCode']. "'");
        $sql = $conn->query("select * from countries order by countryName");

        if($selectedrow = $selected->fetch_assoc()){
             echo "<option selected value='" . $selectedrow['countryName']."'>". $selectedrow['countryName']."</option>";
        }
         //echo "<select>";

        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value ='". $row['countryName']."'>". $row['countryName']."</option>";
        }
        //echo "</select>";
        $conn->close();
       ?> 
    </select><br>

    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['phone']); ?>"><br>

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['email']); ?>" 
           size="50"><br>

    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['password']); ?>"><br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Customer"><br>
</form>
<p><a href="">Search Customers</a></p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
elseif ($app_state == "processed") {
  if ($firstName == "Vincent") {
    $app_state = "Logged in";
}
}

if ($app_state == "Logged in") {
echo("Logged in<br> Hello Vincent</body></html>");
}
?>

<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

index.php(to process the data):

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/customer_db.php');

 $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
 if ($action === NULL) {
   $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
 if ($action === NULL) {
    $action = 'search_customers';
}
}

 //instantiate variable(s)
 $last_name = '';
 $customers = array();

 if ($action == 'search_customers') {   
    include('customer_search.php');
 } else if ($action == 'display_customers') {
    $last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last_name');
 if (empty($last_name)) {
    $message = 'You must enter a last name.';
  } else {
    $customers = get_customers_by_last_name($last_name);
  }
  include('customer_search.php');
 } else if ($action == 'display_customer') {
    $customer_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customer_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $customer = get_customer($customer_id);

   include('customer_display.php');
 } else if ($action == 'update_customer') {
 $customer_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customer_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
 $first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'first_name');
 //echo $first_name;


$last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last_name');
$address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'address');
$city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'city');
$state = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'state');
$postal_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'postal_code');
$country_name = $_POST["selected"];
$phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

//if(!$valid_fname == null){require ('customer_display.php');};
//echo $country_name;
$country_code = get_countryCode($country_name); 

update_customer($customer_id, $first_name, $last_name,
        $address, $city, $state, $postal_code, $country_code,
        $phone, $email, $password);

include('customer_search.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: not going trough all that code, only post what is relevant

Answer (score 0):

You have no name attribute with the value of 'action', so your update never happens.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="update_customer">
    <!-- rest of the form -->
</form>
```

Edited for clarity.